# What is the equivalent of The Little Lisper project in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lisp, bootstrap, lambda-calculus

In the book [The Little Lisper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0023397632), you implement a minimal Scheme in 10 Chapters that is capable of interpreting any chapter in the book.

To me it seems you could do the same for a 'minimal subset of a typed language' to be self-bootstrapping. I'm trying to work out what is feasible.

To me the options are:

- Simply Typed Lambda Calculus
- System F
- Miranda
- Haskell subset

**Assumptions:**

- Note that I'm ignoring the GHC runtime elements like spineless tagless graph-interpreter

My question is: **What is the equivalent of the Little Lisper project in Haskell?**

Comment: Possibly the ongoing ["Write you a Haskell"](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/) work can be of some interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a quite useful [tutorial by Oleg Kiselyov and Chung-chieh Shan](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/AlgorithmsH.html#teval), in which they build a very simple implementation of the simply-typed lambda calculus with Hindley-Milner type inference. IIRC they don't write a parser for their language (you write parse trees in Haskell to use it), but this would clearly be a very simple addition that could be based on a typical parsec tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a article "Typing Haskell With Haskell*". It presents the most problematic part of the question - making the type checker/inferrer for the Haskell language (all code included). As far as I can tell, this makes 1-rank polymorphic language.

For 2+-rank poly you could google for "Boxy Types" (however, there is no code like in THIH, but only hellish type math in form of "modus ponens").